# Insert not working

Tags: php, database, crud, insert-query

I am trying to submit a order form into a database, it's supposed to work in theory but for some reason isn't showing up in the table on the database.

```
$result = "insert into orders(lastname, id, email, roomnumber, typeorder)
    values('".$lastname ."','".$ID ."','".$Email ."','".$RoomNumber ."','".$typeorder ."','" . "0');";
```

Comment: You need to post the complete code that you are using to insert, add error handling and show us what error you are getting.

Comment: Are you using [**deprecated `mysql_` functions**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)? What does the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 4):

You're inserting 6 values for 5 columns...
Remove the '0'

And please, don't use mysql_* instead try [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using data sanitization before running the query anyway. but here is the quick fix and it should work absolutely fine.
$result = "insert into orders(lastname, id, email, roomnumber, typeorder)
    values('".$lastname ."','".$ID ."','".$Email ."','".$RoomNumber ."','".$typeorder ."')";